# Matlab code would not plot part of the function

Tags: matlab, vector, matlab-figure

I tried recently to plot some velocicty fields for a tutorial problem in my fluids problem set. I wrote the following Matlab code

```
clear;

h_theta_multiple=0.01;
h_theta=h_theta_multiple*2*pi;
h_rho=0.1;

[theta,rho] = meshgrid(0:h_theta:2*pi,0:h_rho:5);
[x1,x2] = pol2cart(theta,rho);

N=[1 2 3 -1 -2 -3];

figure
for i=1:length(N)
n=N(i);
u1 = rho.^n .* cos(n.*theta); 
u2 = rho.^n .* sin(n.*theta); 
subplot(2,3,i);
quiver(x1,x2,u1,u2);
end

figure
for i=1:length(N)
n=N(i);
u1 = -rho.^n .* sin(n.*theta); 
u2 = rho.^n .* cos(n.*theta); 
subplot(2,3,i);
quiver(x1,x2,u1,u2);
end
```

It gives me the following
[image: First Function]

[image]

for the first and second functions respectively. I can't quite figure out why it doesn't plot the ones for n is negative... I tried to isolate everything but couldn't quite debug it in the end.

Comment: Interesting, the data is indeed there, but you can not see it. `quiver(x1,x2,u1,u2,'o')` will show it.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Yeah I just tried that and it works but I do want the vector form. It is so weird.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that for negative `n` the matrices `u1` and `u2` contain infinite values in some entries. `quiver` auto-scales the values, so everything gets compressed down to zero and thus does not show in the graph.

A solution is to replace infinite values by `NaN`:

```
clear;

h_theta_multiple=0.01;
h_theta=h_theta_multiple*2*pi;
h_rho=0.1;

[theta,rho] = meshgrid(0:h_theta:2*pi,0:h_rho:5);
[x1,x2] = pol2cart(theta,rho);

N=[1 2 3 -1 -2 -3];

figure
for i=1:length(N)
n=N(i);
u1 = rho.^n .* cos(n.*theta); 
u2 = rho.^n .* sin(n.*theta); 
u1(isinf(u1)) = NaN; % replace infinite values by NaN
u2(isinf(u2)) = NaN;
subplot(2,3,i);
quiver(x1,x2,u1,u2);
end

figure
for i=1:length(N)
n=N(i);
u1 = -rho.^n .* sin(n.*theta); 
u2 = rho.^n .* cos(n.*theta); 
u1(isinf(u1)) = NaN; % replace infinite values by NaN
u2(isinf(u2)) = NaN;
subplot(2,3,i);
quiver(x1,x2,u1,u2);
end
```

This gives

[image]

[image]

Comment: Oh yes of course, for the first iteration it is finding 1/0^n and hence the Inf values. Don't know why I didn't just have a look at the u1 and u2 arrays. Thanks a lot!